JPA query not giving the same result as pgAdmin
So I'm tryna query all the rooms that do not have a reservation in the given check_in and check_out, for doing so I'm using the above query :
When I test the logic of query on pgAdmin it works fine, but it not produces the same entity when I use it as a native query on my repository ...
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM \"room\" r " +
            "WHERE r.\"id\" NOT IN (" +
            "SELECT rv.\"room_id\" " +
            "FROM \"reservation\" rv " +
            "WHERE :checkInDate < rv.\"check_out\" " +
            "AND :checkOutDate > rv.\"check_in\") " +
            "AND r.\"kids\" = :kids " +
            "AND r.\"adult\" = :adults",
            nativeQuery = true)
    List<Room> findAvailableRooms(@Param("checkInDate") LocalDate checkInDate,
                                  @Param("checkOutDate") LocalDate checkOutDate,
                                  @Param("kids") int kids,
                                  @Param("adults") int adults);

package com.example.hotelManagmentSystem.dataproviders.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "reservation")
public class Reservation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")
    private Hotel hotel;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "client_id")
    private User client;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "room_id")
    private Room room;

    @Column(name = "check_in")
    private LocalDate checkIn;

    @Column(name = "check_out")
    private LocalDate checkOut;

    @Column(name = "adults")
    private Integer adults;

    @Column(name = "kids")
    private Integer kids;

    @Column(name = "net_value")
    private Double netValue;

    @Column(name = "tax_rate")
    private Double taxRate;

    @Column(name = "discount")
    private Double discount;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private LocalDate createdAt;

    @Column(name = "total")
    private Double total;

}

package com.example.hotelManagmentSystem.dataproviders.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.*;
import lombok.*;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "room")
public class Room {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id")
    private Hotel hotel;

    @Column(name = "type")
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "adult")
    private Integer adult;

    @Column(name = "kids")
    private Integer kids;

    @Column(name = "description", length = Integer.MAX_VALUE)
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "room")
    private Set<RoomPrice> roomPrices;

}

I tried to use a left join and get all rows where reservation is null and still reproduces the same result,
Tried to change the FetchType from lazy to eager on room inside reservation attribute ...

Above is the full code:
https://github.com/MaksimoRamaj/hotelManagmentV2

Compilation of your project fails with Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to determine Dialect without JDBC metadata (please set 'jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url' for common cases or 'hibernate.dialect' when a custom Dialect implementation must be provided) 

Hey Alex, i think it is caused by environmental variables take a look at application properties, db name , port number ecc are defined as environmental variables

Ok, now tests fails. Can you be more specific? How did you decide that results are different? And what is the difference? You wrote in your question nativeQuery=true but in the project in GitHub I don't see that. Please provide reproducible example with README where explain what should be set in environment, shall table be created earlier, shall they be filled with data and so on

Ok, so I want to get all rooms that do not have a reservation between the checkin and checkout dates requested by the client, i use postgresql and the below query to do the filtration : //SELECT * FROM "room" r WHERE r."id" not IN (SELECT res."room_id" FROM "reservation" res WHERE ('2024-06-14' < res.check_out AND '2024-06-17' > res.check_in) AND (r.kids = 2 AND r.adult = 2))
//
directly in db it gives me the exact records... but the same query converted as JPQL query gives me all rooms not filtering based on checkin and checkout ,,,
Do not consider unit testing I'm testing it manually..

I'm testing it manually by populating the databse

About the nativeQuery=true I think when I did the pull request I had changed the query trying different queries that reproduce the same result

I'm adding right now liquibase changelogs, which will be helpful in automatically populating the database tables ...

I can manually execute select statement in psql client but I can not manually execute it in repository. I need some integration test. Can you write it?

And yes, changelogs will be helpful for me if they are written in pure SQL. If not please include liquibase in the project

Ok Alex it will require for me some time to do those since in the next two days I have 2 exams :), I really appreciate your help :)

Hey @Alex how you doing, I can't understand why but now the same query is working fine, the only change I made was dropping the database schema and re-creating it by liquibase changelogs ...

Hi Maksimo, I will help you. There might be several reasons for this discrepancy, different queries, different parameters, may be different drivers an so on. I will try to reproduce it but I need more info - what is the result here and there, what were the parameters, what sql did you used in dbeaver, and more inserted data. I see in the second change log only 2 tables filled

Also added an issue to your project
